# How can I list all environment variables configured in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I configured AWS provider in Terraform by providing an access key and secret as environment variables according to the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs):

`$ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="anaccesskey"` 
`$ export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="asecretkey"`

I now want to view those variables on the console as well as other environment variables configured on my system but I can't find the right command.

**Update:** I found out that I didn't configure the AWS provider like I thought. The AWS CLI was already configured with my credentials stored in [AWS credentials file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html): `~/.aws/credentials`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your command line, run `printenv`

Reference: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/printenv.1.html

Comment: Indeed, running `printenv` returns system environment variables but I don't recognize any of them to be Terraform variables, such as the mentioned access key ID and secret access key. Any suggestions on how to run a similar command under Terraform's context?

Comment: @randvir Terraform uses that same "context". https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/environment-variables.html

Comment: I found out my question is flawed. I discovered that I configured the AWS CLI to store credentials inside the AWS credentials file, not inside environment variables. Your answer helped me realize I'm looking in the wrong place and also taught me how to view environment variables. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your current shell environment variables, which are also including terraform-related ones can be listed by `env` command or you can do it in tf file:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.12.0"
}

resource "null_resource" "get_tf_env" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "env"
    interpreter = ["bash", "-c"]
  }
}
```

According to [official docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/environment-variables.html) you can only feed terraform with the envs starting with `TF_*`.

Answer (score 1):

`printenv | grep TF_VAR` will list all variables that you defined.